# Running application with only some parts in a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I wanted to know if an application which is being managed by Kubernetes, like [Jupiter](https://github.com/anrgusc/jupiter) would work if some elements of it like the CIRCE dispatcher are used without a container.

If yes, then broadly what kind of changes are required to be made? Also, are there any resources from where I can read up on this? Thanks !!

Comment: What do you mean by *"without the container"* ? Do you want to run this particular component outside your **kubernetes cluster** ?

Comment: Running a database outside the cluster is fairly routine, and there's not really anything special about it, just set your application database configuration to point at it.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can integrate any external component (deployed outside your **kuberntes cluster**) with components running within the cluster, so that it becomes an integral part of your application architecture.

You can achieve it with so-called [service without selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).

Its most common use cases are described in kubernetes documentation but it can be used to integrate practically any external component with your kubernetes cluster:

> Services most commonly abstract access to Kubernetes Pods, but they
>   can also abstract other kinds of backends. For example:
>
> - You want to have an external database cluster in production, but in your test environment you use your own databases.
> - You want to point your Service to a Service in a different  [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces)
>     or on another cluster.
> - You are migrating a workload to Kubernetes. Whilst evaluating the approach, you run only a proportion of your backends in Kubernetes.

Below you have example how it may look like:

> In any of these scenarios you can define a Service  *without*  a Pod
>   selector. For example:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> spec:
>   ports:
>     - protocol: TCP
>       port: 80
>       targetPort: 9376
> ```
>
> Because this Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint
>   object is  *not*  created automatically. You can manually map the
>   Service to the network address and port where it’s running, by adding
>   an Endpoint object manually:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Endpoints
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> subsets:
>   - addresses:
>       - ip: 192.0.2.42
>     ports:
>       - port: 9376
> ```
>
> Accessing a Service without a selector works the same as if it had a
>   selector. In the example above, traffic is routed to the single
>   endpoint defined in the YAML:  `192.0.2.42:9376`  (TCP).

Also take a look at `ExternalName` which is a special kind of `Service` without a selector:

> An `ExternalName` `Service` is a special case of `Service` that does
>   not have selectors and uses DNS names instead. For more information,
>   see the 
>   [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)
>   section later in this document.

You can also read this two articles which basically explain the same thing:

[Kubernetes best practices: mapping external services](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)

[Kubernetes Access External Services](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-access-external-services-e4fd643e5097)

Please let me know if it helps. If not, please explain in more detail the desired state you want to achieve.