# How to access locally installed postgresql in microk8s cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, microk8s

I have installed Postgresql and microk8s on Ubuntu 18.
One of my microservice which is inside microk8s single node cluster needs to access postgresql installed on same VM.
Some articles suggesting that I should create service.yml and endpoint.yml like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgresql
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 5432
   targetPort: 5432

---

kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgresql
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: ?????
   ports:
     - port: 5432
```

Now, I am not getting what should I put in **subsets.addresses.ip** field ?

Comment: How have you deployed your **Postgresql** ? Could you share your `Deployment` or maybe `StatefulSet` defitition `yaml` ?

Comment: I installed Postgresql using apt-get install

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I haven't read carefully enough all the details :) You actually mentioned that **microk8s cluster** and **postgres** are installed on the same vm. As to your question, It can be done pretty easily. I'll post my answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to configure your **Postgresql** to listen not only on your vm's `localhost`. Let's assume you have a network interface with IP address `10.1.2.3`, which is configured on your node, on which **Postgresql** instance is installed.

Add the following entry in your `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,10.1.2.3'
```

and restart your postgres service:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

You can check if it listens on the desired address by running:

```
sudo ss -ntlp | grep postgres
```

From your `Pods` deployed within your **Microk8s cluster** you should be able to reach IP addresses of your node e.g. you should be able to ping mentioned `10.1.2.3` from your `Pods`.

As it doesn't require any loadbalancing you can reach to your **Postgresql** directly from your `Pods` without a need of configuring additional `Service`, that exposes it to your cluster.

If you don't want to refer to your **Postgresql** instance in your application using it's IP address, you can edit your `Deployment` (which manages the set of `Pods` that connect to your postgres db) to modify the default content of `/etc/hosts` file used by your `Pods`.

Edit your app Deployment by running:

```
microk8s.kubectl edit deployment your-app
```

and add the following section under `Pod` template `spec`:

```
  hostAliases: # it should be on the same indentation level as "containers:"
  - hostnames:
    - postgres
    - postgresql
    ip: 10.1.2.3
```

After saving it, all your `Pods` managed by this `Deployment` will be recreated according to the new specification. When you exec into your `Pod` by running:

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -ti pod-name -- /bin/bash
```

you should see additional section in your /etc/hosts file:

```
# Entries added by HostAliases.
10.1.2.3    postgres    postgresql
```

Since now you can refer to your **Postgres** instance in your app by names `postgres:5432` or `postgresql:5432` and it will be resolved to your VM's IP address.

I hope it helps.

## UPDATE:

I almost forgot that some time ago I've posted an answer on a very similar topic. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096013/11714114). It describes the usage of a **Service without selector**, which is basically what you mentioned in your question. And yes, it also can be used for configuring access to your **Postgresql** instance running on the same host. As this kind of `Service` doesn't have selectors by its definition, **no endpoint** is automatically created by **kubernetes** and you need to create one by yourself. Once you have the IP address of your **Postgres** instance (in our example it is `10.1.2.3`) you can use it in your **endpoint** definition.

Once you configure everything on the side of **kubernetes** you may still encounter an issue with **Postgres**. In your `Pod` that is trying to connect to the **Postgres** instance you may see the following error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host 10.1.7.151
```

It basically means that your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file lacks the required entry that would allow your `Pod` to access your **Postgresql** database. Authentication is host-based, so in other words only hosts with certain IPs or with IPs within certain IP range are allowed to authenticate.

> Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which
>   traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database
>   cluster's data directory. (HBA stands for host-based authentication.)

So now you probably wonder which network you should allow in your `pg_hba.conf`. To handle cluster networking **Microk8s** uses [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel#flannel). Take a look at the content of your `/var/snap/microk8s/common/run/flannel/subnet.env` file. Mine looks as follows:

```
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.1.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.1.53.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1410
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=false
```

Adding to your `pg_hba.conf` only **flannel subnet** should be enough to ensure that all your `Pods` can connect to **Posgresql**.

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I tried this, I got error in pod `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host 10.1.7.151`

Comment: And if I am not wrong then I should not add this above IP in pg_hba.conf as it may get change if new pod gets created.

Comment: `That's why you need to make this configuration a permanent part of your Pods` 
Can you elaborate which configuration you talking about ?

Comment: Forget it. My mistake. I looked at it from `Pod's` perspective as as if it was in **Postgres** logs. Let's summarize and clarify: **Host based authentication** configuration is set on your **Postgresql** instance and you already told that **Postgres** instance is not part of your **kubernetes cluster** but it is installed using apt-get on your VM, the same one, on which you run your **microk8s cluster**, right ? But when you are trying to connect to it from your `Pod` you could see in its logs the above error, that it cannot be authenticated as for its IP there is no entry in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: You're right, `Pods` IPs are ephemeral and are subject to change every time a `Pod` is recreated, so it makes no sense to add static entries for **single IP** in your `pg_hba.conf` as it won't work. But note that these are not just any random IPs. They are part of specific **subnet**, which can be added to `pg_hba.conf` instead of individual **IPs**. This way you can authenticate all your `Pods` as they will always have **IPs** within a specific range.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/276): *IP range 10.1.1.0/24, 10.152.183.0/24 are userd for cluster or pods by default.*. And it is also explains where they can be customized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209630/discussion-between-bhushan-and-mario).